# Cumulative sum between two timeserie events

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a following timeseries data in bigquery:

```
Timestamp                   EventID   Value
2022-03-05 06:00:10          1         NULL
2022-03-05 06:00:11          3         5
2022-03-05 06:00:12          2         3  
2022-03-05 06:00:13          3         2 
2022-03-05 06:00:14          4         1          
2022-03-05 06:00:17          2         6 
2022-03-05 06:00:17          5         NULL
2022-03-05 06:30:15          1         NULL
2022-03-05 06:30:18          3         2 
2022-03-05 06:31:22          2         4 
2022-03-05 06:35:56          3         3 
2022-03-05 06:36:18          4         1 
2022-03-05 06:39:17          2         2
2022-03-05 06:50:24          5         NULL
```

I want to write a SQL query to sum values having the same eventID between eventId 1 and eventId 5.
The output will look like that:

```
StartEventId    EndEventId      StartTime             EndTime              total_2   total_3   total_4 
1               5               2022-03-05 06:00:10   2022-03-05 06:00:17   9        7          1
1               5               2022-03-05 06:30:15   2022-03-05 06:50:24   6        5          1
```

total_2 is the sum of values having eventId equal 2 between eventID 1 and 5. The same for total_3 and total_4.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select min(EventID) StartEventId,  max(EventID) EndEventId,
  min(Timestamp) StartTime,  max(Timestamp) EndTime,
  sum(if(EventID = 2, Value, null)) total_2,
  sum(if(EventID = 3, Value, null)) total_3,
  sum(if(EventID = 4, Value, null)) total_4
from (
  select *, div(countif(EventID in (1,5)) over win - 1, 2) grp
  from your_table
  window win as (order by Timestamp, EventID)
)
group by grp
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: awesome, you are my hero! thank you.